# Why did this code still work?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Some old code that I just came across:

```
MLIST * new_mlist_link()
{
    MLIST *new_link = (MLIST * ) malloc(sizeof(MLIST));
    new_link->next  = NULL;
    new_link->mapi  = NULL;
    new_link->result = 0;
}
```

This was being called to build a linked list, however I noticed there is no statement:

```
return new_link;
```

Even without the return statement there, the list still got built properly. Why did this happen?

*Edit:* Platform: Mandriva 2009 64bit Linux 2.6.24.7-server  GCC 4.2.3-6mnb1

*Edit:* Funny... this code also ran successfuly on about 5 different Linux installations, all different versions/flavors, as well as a Mac.

Comment: There's no possible answer aside from dumb luck, unless (or maybe even if) you let us know what platform.

Comment: This makes a good case for using a static code checker.

Comment: Interesting that it ran on so many platforms.  It only has one local variable, so it must be pretty standard for GCC on the Intel to store a single local variable in the EAX (or its 64-bit equivalent), and also to use that register for return values.

Comment: So, if you declare a variable to return at the top of a function, is GCC smart enough to use EAX for it from the start?

Comment: I think that makes a good case for something like `-Werror=return-type`.

Comment: Add a `char * s = "wtf?!";` line at the end of the function and watch it crash (would still compile but won't run as expected). Apparently, if you don't have a return statement, it just returns (or the calling function assumes so) the last local variable declared in that function. Don't rely on this for serious things.

Comment: @Amarghosh: Unless *s* is optimized out as unused. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On 32-bit Windows, most of the time, the return value from a function is left in the EAX register.  Similar setups are used in other OSes, though of course it's compiler-specific.  This particular function presumably stored the new_link variable in that same location, so when you returned without a return, the variable in that location was treated as the return value by the caller.

This is non-portable and very dangerous to actually do, but is also one of the little things that makes programming in C so much fun.

Comment: +1, with the addition that it is the ABI, not the operating system that defines the calling convention.

Comment: That explains why it ran, but why it compiled is the next question. :P You'd think the compiler would check for a return statement (I know all mine do). Either way, while it works, it can definitely be labeled a Bad Thing.

Comment: I think that this style of coding was more common 30ish years ago when C was becoming popular.  The project that this code came from was probably written by an older coder (or just a long time ago) and had since had compiler warnings disabled so that this would compile correctly.

Comment: Nice, specific answer to a strange phenomenon.  I should ask you about the flying objects I've been seeing late at night ;-)

Comment: I think that this is not 32-bit Windows specific... I think that this is the calling convention in the whole IA-32 architecture, but I had to check with the Intel manuals.

Comment: @peachykeen gcc will warn about this with `-Wall` but what confounds me is why the language spec does not make this a mandatory compiler error. I can't think of any reason why it would be a good idea to allow this.

Comment: This would be one of the most subtley sadistic pieces of intentionally smelly code i have ever seen - some old timer who first learnt to program straight machine code on a mainframe has decided to leave a little gem for future generations to ponder over. Nice.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent trick to pull in the Underhanded C contest.  Change a method so it has a path without a return on it.

Comment: Does -Wall catch this on gcc?

Comment: @Bryan: Yes, [`-Wall`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) turns on `-Wreturn-type`.

Comment: +1 for "the little things that make programming in C so much fun"

Comment: The return value was set by malloc and simply not changed by the remainder of the code in the function.  If you compare the assembly output with and without a return statement it should be identical.

Comment: @Tyler: The compiler is allowed to (non-fatally) diagnose this, as it always is for anything.  However, requiring that lack of a return statement be an error fails in the general case with standard C, since you can't indicate functions that never return (e.g. something that calls abort or longjmp): `int f() { int n = might_abort(); if (n) return n; do_longjmp(); }`

Answer (score 7):

Possible it just used the EAX register which normally stores the return value of the last function that was called. This is not good practice at all! The behavior for this sort of things is undefined.. But it is cool to see work ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It's basically luck; apparently, the compiler happens to stick new_link into the same place it would stick a returned value.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid this problem, use:

`-Wreturn-type`:

> Warn whenever a function is defined with a return-type that defaults to int. Also warn about any return statement with no return-value in a function whose return-type is not void (falling off the end of the function body is considered returning without a value), and about a return statement with an expression in a function whose return-type is void.

`-Werror=return-type` to turn the above into an error:

> Make the specified warning into an error. The specifier for a warning is appended, for example -Werror=switch  turns the warnings controlled by -Wswitch into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate -Werror  for specific warnings, for example -Wno-error=switch  makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect. You can use the -fdiagnostics-show-option option to have each controllable warning amended with the option which controls it, to determine what to use with this option.

*(from [GCCs warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html))*

Answer (score 1):

This works by coincidence. You shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that it'll produce a very hard to find bug. I'm unsure where I read it, but I recall that if you forget to put in a return statement, most compilers will default to return void.

Here's a short example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* getVal();

int main()
{
        int *v = getVal();
        cout << "Value is: " << *v << endl;
        return 0;
}

int* getVal()
{
        // return nothing here
}
```

For me, this works as well. However, when I run it, I get a segment fault. So it's really undefined. Just because it compiles, doesn't mean it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

It works because in the 1940's when the C language was created, there was no `return` keyword. If you look in the "functions" section of the C43 MINSI standard, it has this to say on the subject (amongst other things):

```
16.4.3b For backwards compatibility the EAX register MUST be used to return
        the address of the first chunk of memory allocated by malloc.
```

`</humour>`

Comment: No, it isn't.  There is no C43 MINSI standard, he's just making this up.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a coincidence:

The space for the return value of the function is allocated ahead of time. Since that value is uninitialized, it could have pointed to the same space on the heap as the memory allocated for the struct.

Comment: Uhh, no, returned values are usually returned in registers, or, I suppose, on the stack.  It's not a random pointer being mysteriously correct.  Return values are not allocated.

Comment: As indicated above, return values are returned in a register if they fit, as would be the case for a pointer.

Comment: @Whirl: On some architectures, space is reserved on the stack for return values when a procedure is invoked. On others, the result is returned in a register. It **differs**.